# Ways to push all the github logs like Audit logs , github actions logs to AWS cloud watch

Tags: github, amazon-cloudwatch

Ways to push all the github logs like Audit logs , github actions logs to AWS cloud watch

did not find any options from google.

please someone help me with different options if you know any .if possible with some explanation

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.